# Indpendence inequality over interval: $\mathbb{P}[a<X<b]\leq\mathbb{P}[a<X]\mathbb{P}[X<b]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to show the following:

$$\mathbb{P}[a<X<b]\leq\mathbb{P}[a<X]\mathbb{P}[X<b]$$

where $X$ is any random variable and $a,b$ are constants. I feel I am missing the obvious here, but does the below proof hold?

$$\mathbb{P}[a<X<b]=\mathbb{P}[a<X|X < b]\mathbb{P}[X<b]\leq \mathbb{P}[a<X]\mathbb{P}[X<b]$$

I used the inequality $\mathbb{P}[a<X|X < b]\leq \mathbb{P}[a<X]$ which I am fairly sure holds but am struggling to show. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: How do you define the left side of the inequality you used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting Maximilian Janisch's comment, a simpler way without using conditional probability (assuming $a <b$ as otherwise you get $0 \le $ the product of two probabilities, so clearly true) may be

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\mathbb P(a<X<b)&=&\mathbb P(X<b)-\mathbb P(X\le a) \\
&\le& \mathbb P(X<b) -\mathbb P(X<b)\,\mathbb P(X\le a)  \\
&=& \mathbb P(X<b)\, (1-\mathbb P(X\le a)) \\
&=& \mathbb P(X<b)\,\mathbb P(a <X).\end{array}$$

---

Your statement $\mathbb{P}(a<X\mid X < b) \le \mathbb{P}(a<X)$ is correct so long as $\mathbb P(X<b) >0$,  because (still assuming $a<b$) $$\mathbb{P}(a<X\mid X < b) = 1-\frac{\mathbb{P}(X \le a)}{\mathbb P(X<b)} \le 1-\mathbb{P}(X \le a) = \mathbb{P}(a < X)$$ since $\mathbb P(X<b)\le 1$.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(t) = P(X\leq t)$ be the CDF of $X$.

First we consider the related inequality
$$P(a < X \leq b) = F(b)-F(a) \leq F(b)(1-F(a)) = P(X\leq b)P(X>a)$$
Now using that $P(X<b) =\lim_{t\uparrow b} F(t)$ we get
$$P(a<X<b) = \lim_{t\uparrow b} P(a<X\leq t) \leq \lim_{t\uparrow b} P(X\leq t)P(X>a) =P(X<b)P(X>a)$$
which concludes the argument.

Comment: You can do this without taking a limit directly: $$\mathbb P(a<X<b)=\mathbb P(X<b)-\mathbb P(X\le a) \le \mathbb P(X<b) (1-\mathbb P(X\le a)) = \mathbb P(X<b)\mathbb P(X>a).$$

Comment: Right, yes thank you!